# netbeans 7.3 not recognizing html tags

Tags: netbeans, editor, code-editor

I just update my netbeans 7.3 and after the update the editor did not recognize the html tag. I searched over the google but i never got a proper answer.  Is there a theme that i can use to make netbeans recognize the HTML tags?

Comment: I'm working with HTML and JSP with Netbeans 7.3 and everything is fine, but I installed from scratch, personally I don't like updates. Check installed packages, try to reinstall the PHP packages.